# Hidden ext4 partition?

Tags: partition, devices

Is there a way to hide an `ext4` partition from e.g `Thunar`?

And the `open file/save` dialog , I think they come from the same source.

Comment: so unmount it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you mean hiding an unmounted partition from thunar, add a row in your `/etc/fstab`, using `none` as the mount point and fs type columns ;)